# Unable to connect to WAMP router on the client side of my application

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, autobahn, wamp-protocol

I'm building a web interface to an IoT device that will change the settings of the device. The tech stack that i'm using is as follows:
 - React.JS for the front end client
 - Node.js for the server
 - AutobahnJS library to communicate with WAMP to make RPC calls, Subscribe/Publish events.

On my client side, I'm trying to make a connection to my WAMP router w/ autobahn with the following code

```
//Define our WAMP connection via autobahn
var url = 'ws://{ip}:{port}/';
var realm = 'com.example.embedded.api';
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({url: url, realm: realm});
console.log(connection);

connection.onopen = function (session) {
  console.log("connected to WAMP router");
  app.session = session;
  console.log("connection to app success");
};

connection.onclose = function (reason, details) {
  console.log("WAMP connection closed", reason, details);
  app.session = null;
}

connection.open();
```

This connection fails. When I log out the issue in the console the error message is

> websocket.js:167 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://{ipaddress}' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://{ip}:{port}/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.

I'm not sure why my error message is telling me that the endpoint over WSS. I'm able to connect to that endpoint point on my code server.

```
//point to react build
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));

//create a server
const server = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
}, app)
.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}! Go to https://localhost`)
});

//open up a websocket
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
console.log("wss", wss);

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });
  ws.send('something');
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: It's unclear what question you're asking for us to help you with.  The error you are getting seems entirely self explanatory and there's no way to work-around that other than connection your webSocket over wss or downgrading the page to http.  Yes, you can let your server work as a proxy to the device and then your server can connect to it over ws just fine.  You say you can't get that working, but you don't show any of your effort to do that so there's nothing to go on for us to help you with that.  I'm not sure we can help you given the state of your question.

Comment: I'm not sure how to properly establish an endpoint over wss. I'm under the impression that the code that i've written on the client side open's up a WS connection in order for me to make calls. I'm just using Node to host the static page.

Comment: If what you're trying to ask about is how to make a wss connection from your client page to your Express server, then please edit the question to ask specifically about that and show the code you tried and what problems you ran into.  If what you're trying to ask about is how to make a ws connection from your Express server to the IoT device, then edit the question to ask specifically about that and show the code you tried and what problems you ran into.  Right now you have an unclear question with downvotes and closevotes.  You need to fix the question.

Comment: Just to be clear, the way this place works, you can certainly help people understand in your comments, but your comments cannot be the only way people can understand what you're really asking - you must edit the question itself to be clear.

Comment: Ok thank you for your candor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure why my error message is telling me that the endpoint over WSS. I'm able to connect to that endpoint point on my code server.

The error message you get is telling you that the web page is loaded via https.  That means that any other resources the page connects to or loads need to also be secure.  But, your code for the webSocket connection is not secure.  It's using `ws://xxx` which is insecure.  This code:

```
//Define our WAMP connection via autobahn
var url = 'ws://{ip}:{port}/';
var realm = 'com.example.embedded.api';
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({url: url, realm: realm});
```

Is using a `ws://` url which is insecure.  If the main web page is loaded via https, then browsers enforce that other resources used by the page must also be loaded via secure links.

To fix this, the possible choices are:

1. Use `wss://xxx` to connect securely.
2. Change the page so it loaded insecurely over `http` (not recommended).
3. Change the way you connect to the resource so that you proxy the connection to the resource through a secure link to your server.